# notifyPropertyChanged on MutableRealmInteger

Tags: android, data-binding, realm

I'm using `Realm` and `data binding`.
Before `MutableRealmInteger`, I used regular primitive type and used its setter, and UI changed automatically with the new value.
Now I want to use `MutableRealmInteger` type, but I don't know how to notify the UI of changes.

This is a part of my model:

```
public class MyModel extends RealmObject implements Observable {
...
public final MutableRealmInteger NewWayAAA = MutableRealmInteger.valueOf(0);
private String oldWayAAA = "0";
...

@Bindable
public String getOldWayAAA() {
    return oldWayAAA.isEmpty() ? "0" : oldWayAAA;
}

public void setOldWayAAA (String param) {
    if (!param.isEmpty()) {
        this.oldWayAAA= param;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.oldwayaaa);
    }
}

...

/**
 * Notifies listeners that all properties of this instance have changed.
 */
public synchronized void notifyChange() {
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.notifyCallbacks(this, 0, null);
    }
}

/**
 * Notifies listeners that a specific property has changed. The getter for the property
 * that changes should be marked with {@link Bindable} to generate a field in
 * <code>BR</code> to be used as <code>fieldId</code>.
 *
 * @param fieldId The generated BR id for the Bindable field.
 */
public void notifyPropertyChanged(int fieldId) {
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.notifyCallbacks(this, fieldId, null);
    }
}

@Override
public void addOnPropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChangedCallback onPropertyChangedCallback) {
    if (mCallbacks == null) {
        mCallbacks = new PropertyChangeRegistry();
    }
    mCallbacks.add(onPropertyChangedCallback);
}

@Override
public void removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChangedCallback onPropertyChangedCallback) {
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.remove(onPropertyChangedCallback);
    }
}
```

`MutableRealmInteger` doesn't have setter and the usage of it is:

```
myModelIns.NewWayAAA.increment(10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyModel extends RealmObject implements Observable {
    ...
    private final MutableRealmInteger NewWayAAA = MutableRealmInteger.valueOf(0);
    ...

    @Bindable
    public int getNewWayAAA() {
        return NewWayAAA.getValue();
    }

    public void incrementNewWayAAA() {
        NewWayAAA.increment();
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.newwayaaa);
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Shame on me :))